# Animate a div across screen with angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

At the moment, I have a div with the following on it:

```
<div ng-style="{'left': PageMap.ColumnWrap.OverviewPanelLeft + 'px'}"></div>
```

when I press the right key, I attach the event to change the `PageMap.ColumnWrap.OverviewPanelLeft` to another number. This obviously flicks the div to that point. Perfect.

Now instead of flicking to that point, i'd like to animate to that point using an animation framework that has easing etc.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need animation framework in this case. just simple transition rule in CSS will do the trick:

```css
div {
    transition: left .5s ease;    
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease;    
}
```

Obviously, you it's better to make selector more specific (class, parent selector, etc.), you don't want transition to apply to all div elements.

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.PageMap = {ColumnWrap: {OverviewPanelLeft: 50}};
    
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.PageMap.ColumnWrap.OverviewPanelLeft = 150;
    }, 1000)
});
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: coral;
    transition: left .5s ease;    
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>    

<section ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-style="{'left': PageMap.ColumnWrap.OverviewPanelLeft + 'px'}"></div>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class with transition to the element.

```
<div class="moveAnimation" ng-style="{'left': PageMap.ColumnWrap.OverviewPanelLeft + 'px'}"></div>

.moveAnimation{
transition: left 0.5s;
}
```